# Google Marketplace Authorization for apps (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to make an application that I can put in the marketplace to read content from a spreadsheet.

In my local developments in java, my authorization is always of the following type:

```
credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder ()
.setTransport (HTTP_TRANSPORT)
.setJsonFactory (JSON_FACTORY)
.setServiceAccountId ("sample")
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File (f)
.setServiceAccountScopes (SCOPES)
.setServiceAccountUser ("sample")
.build ();
```

How do you do to install the app and authorize have all the permissions, how is that code to get credentials without using a p12?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of P12 you can donwload a JSON-version of the key and create `GoogleCredentials` with a single call.

Here you go:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential#fromStream(java.io.InputStream)